# Ionic run android "cordova is not avaliable"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I recently upgraded Ionic and cordova. now when I try to run my ionic project

```
ionic cordova run android -c
```

i receive

```
[20:52:04]  console.warn: Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to
        include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
[20:52:04]  console.warn: Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include
        cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
[20:52:29]  console.warn: Native: tried accessing the GoogleMaps plugin but Cordova is not available. Make sure to
        include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
```

I have removed the android platform and readded it.

I have tried

```
<script src="../node_modules/cordova/cordova.js"></script>

<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

not sure if this helps but my package.json

```
  {
  "name": "***",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
"build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
"ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
 },
 "dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "5.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
"@angular/core": "5.0.3",
"@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
"@angular/http": "5.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
"@ionic-native/camera": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
"@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
"@ionic/pro": "1.0.16",
"@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
"cordova-ios": "~4.3.1",
"firebase": "^4.9.1",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.5.2",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.18",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "~1.3.1",
"cordova-plugin-device": "~1.1.4",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.11",
"cordova-plugin-camera": "~2.4.1",
"cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "~2.2.5",
"cordova-android": "~7.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
"typescript": "2.4.2"
},
"description": "An Ionic project",
"cordova": {
"platforms": [
  "ios",
  "android"
],
"plugins": {
  "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
  "cordova-plugin-device": {},
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
  "cordova-plugin-camera": {
    "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
    "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
  },
  "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
    "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "SECRET",
    "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "SECRET"
  }
}
```

}
   }

I have looked everywhere, but no one seems to have this issue while using the run command, how do I get cordova plugins to work?

EDIT*****
here what I get when I type ionic info

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\luke_\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.3
Node              : v6.11.0
npm               : 3.10.10
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : D:\Android
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: what is your isssue? could u type **ionic info** in your command line in you project directory and post the data here

Comment: @Madpop I have added it

Comment: please post lower section of your config.xml

Comment: remove and add android platform again, it might solve it...if not please post your config.xml